# How to Rotate :before pseudo element when parent is hovered

Tags: css, hover, font-awesome, pseudo-class

I have added font icons to a list like this:

```
a:before {
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    content: "\f015";
    .. etc..
}
```

When the parent anchor tag is hovered, I want this :before pseudo to be rotated. I tried this, but it is not working:

```
a:hover:before {
            -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
            -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
            -o-transform:rotate(360deg);
}
```

Doesnt this work? What can I do to get the rotate effect on the :before element only when the parent is hovered?

Comment: Could you have a container in the `a` tag which has the `:before` styles applied to it then do: `a:hover element:before`?

Comment: @ilovecode No I couldnt in this case since I have to add the `:before` element via css only. Nicolae Olariu's response works for me..

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vlrprbttst/w9SwR/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this out:

```
a:before {
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms 0s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 300ms 0s ease-in-out;

    content: "\f015";
    display: inline-block; //as @Rohit Azad suggested
    font-family: FontAwesome;

    // .. etc ..
}

a:hover:before {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

Have a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nicolaeolariu/uQ73y/1/).

Comment: Used to display:inline-block; not block in a:before

Comment: @Nicolae, Previously I had the transition css added to the `<a>` tag when it wasnt working. Once I added the transition to `a:before` element, the rotate worked. Thank you so much for your answer. :)

Comment: @RohitAzad As long as `:before` and `:after` are elements, in fact, pseudo-elements, you could make them display as block or inline-block as any other element (tag). In this case, a `display: inline-block`, as you suggested, would be better because it doesn't make the a tag drop below its `:before`. So I'm editing my answer to update with `inline-block`.

Comment: I might not even need to mention `display` property at all, do I? Cuz it works for me even without `display` property set.

Comment: @blackops_programmer In order for a CSS transition to work, you always need to specify which properties you want to animate on the element in its first (default) state, using `transition: propToAnimate|all duration delay easing` (of course, taking into consideration browser prefixes :)). Read more on [CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions).

Comment: Default display for :before is `inline` so that's why it works without adding `display`.

Comment: Yeah.. I had `transition: all` in the parent anchor element and it didint work. Once the transition was added to `:before`, it worked nice.

Answer (score 1):

try this css

```
a:hover:before[class*="icon-"] {
     -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(360deg);
    .rotate(360deg);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:
http://jsfiddle.net/yZFR2/

Try using `transform` rule without the prefix for webkit / mozila / opera.
Tested on Firefox.